# Excel problems with £ sign

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm making a spreadsheet and some of the columns have phone numbers included. I keep adding to the sheet, and as I do, the new rows aren't letting me type a leading 0 or the £ sign.

I need to use these a lot and can't individually format each cell as it will waste a lot of time.

Is there a way I can do it so the £ comes up automatically if I just type in numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It is somewhat unclear what you are asking. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify? Have you tried formatting the entire column as currency so any numbers entered would be preceded by the pound sign? Otherwise, format as text will let you type anything.

Comment: To type a number starting with `0`, use a single apostrophe, i.e. `'0123` will show "0123" in the cell, where `0123` will get cut to just "123".  For the Pound sign, does formatting the rows/cells/columns as Currency and choosing the GBP symbol not do it?

Answer (score 0):

If the cells where you require a £ prefix are grouped together in one or more blocks, you can select them all and then format the whole lot at once.

If the  currency cells are interspersed among other cells, then even conditional formatting will not help you as you cannot mark cells as currency cells based on their contents, you can only apply effects to cells already marked as currency cells.

So, if the first case applies hopefully that helps, otherwise unless someone knows something I don't, I'm fairly sure you will have to manually format the currency cells to get your £, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If your rows / columns are arranged regularly, you can use format painter to duplicate the formatting in cells or use "paste special" to apply formatting. That will work on pasting e.g. a 3 row format set into 30 rows in one go.

To format anything that does not start with 0 as currency, use conditional formatting. First format everything as text, choose entire columns/rows/sheet as appropriate and do Choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and insert this formula to the rule:
=LEFT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()))) > "0"

For the format choose number and currency.

"LEFT" will return 1st digit/character in the cell and that INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())) kludge addresses the current cell. If you turn on R1C1 style addressing current cell is simply "RC".

If you have pennies, you have to create this rule as well:
=MID(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),2,1) = "."
and format it as currency
That will take care of 0.99 values